# Changing the Native Token Name in a Private Ethereum Blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, networkid

Can I modify the native currency symbol in a private blockchain using geth to represent 'XXX' instead of 'ETH'? Which part of the go-ethereum/geth source code or file allows this alteration, and can this be defined within the genesis.json file?

Comment: Have you searched for it ?

Comment: Yes, I have searched a lot, but with no results.. I am wondering if it is possible to added in any way at the genesis file..

Comment: @trasgoverde There's nothing in the go-ethereum code that uses ETH as symbol for the currency. There may be some comments or string but it is not part of the blockchain rules. The name used by exchanges is mostly defined by them some use ETH, other use $ETH, XET, etc.

Comment: I have seen thata some forks did it, change the name of the native coin => cheapeth, bsc and others did the fork changing the name of the native coin. Any clues to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, after some new searching, seems that the only way is L2 EVM chains.

Comment: @trasgoverde The name isn't part of the code. For example in Metamask you can give to an Ethereum compatible blockchain its own name.

Answer (score 1):

As in all comments, the symbol ETH and name Ethereum is not part of the code.

You can create an endpoint layer to hide the default RPC calls and provide to the user whatever you want.

An easy way to do that is create a SpringBoot REST API to publish to the world and hide the Execution layer inside a protected VLAN (may be a Docker infra). You create "REST Controllers" to change the default signature methods from the Execution node RPC protocol and give the coin name you want.

You will gain twice because your nodes will be invisible and inaccessible from outside. The only touch point will be your REST API.

I think Binance BNB do it this way, but all its RPC calls still WEB3 compatible using "ETH".